# How to change size of notification in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: notification

I've change the notification from top to bottom right by using "Panel OSD" extension, but i don't know how to change the size, because its too small.
[image]

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually on the installed GNOME-Extensions page [see here](https://extensions.gnome.org/) which lists all available extensions and a tab for those you have installed there is an icon which allows you to configure the extension on the RHS of the page against the extensions listed as installed.

[image]

[image]

I don't have that extension listed personally so the graphic shows some installed on my system which are active where the configure button is seen to be available.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere, can you take a full picture please?

Comment: @fudu added more info.

Comment: @fudu did the extra graphic help?

Comment: sorry, what is the extra graphic?

Comment: the one above the original one - the picture of the Gnome extensions page.